# Locator.fill() only accepts string as argument

Tags: playwright

I need to send a number to a p-inputnumber input field. As per Playwright documents, fill() method only supports sending string and not integer.

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-fill

There is an issue ticket which suggests that playwright team has fixed it however not sure which version it is supported in.
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/16660

Any advice?

I am using version 1.29. I checked playwright version history documentation and couldn't find any reference to the same.

Comment: That feature has the collecting feedback tag. You can go there and add a  reaction to the description.

Comment: Please provide the link. Thank you!

Comment: I think hardkoded is referring to the link in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your integer into a string:

```
n = 333
element = self.page.locator('Some Locator').fill(str(n))
```